# Error when running ''' examples/rllab/stabilizing_the_ring.py'''

Tags: python, sumo, flow-project

when i run the following code,i met the problem, so can you give me some suggestion?

**code**:

```
'''(flow) sean@ubuntu:~/flow$ python examples/rllab/stabilizing_the_ring.py'''
```

**output**:

```
File "/home/sean/Downloads/enter/envs/flow/lib/python3.5/site-packages/lasagne/layers/base.py", line 44, in 
if any(d is not None and d <= 0 for d in self.input_shape):
TypeError: unorderable types: tuple() <= int()
```

Comment: Please post your code

Answer (score 1):

Sorry you're having this difficulty.
This is actually a bug in RLlab that shows up when you use tuple spaces. Would you mind switching to the rllib examples? We are no longer supporting RLlab since that project is no longer being actively developed by its creators.